# Why jQuery returns am element along with prevObject?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am querying for img with jQuery:

```
<div class="crop-image-area" data-uploaded-picture-path="null">
   <img id="image" class="uploaded-image" src="#" />
</div>

console.log($(".crop-image-area .uploaded-image"));
console.log($(".crop-image-area #image"));
console.log($($(".crop-image-area .uploaded-image").get(0)));
```

The result is:

```
[img#image.uploaded-image, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
[img#image.uploaded-image, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
[img#image.uploaded-image]
```

Why in the first two cases I get `img` object alogn with `prevObject`?

Comment: It's because the first two logs are jQuery objects. The last one is an Element object.

Comment: `.get(0)` unwraps it from the jQuery wrapper. The other two are wrapped in jQuery objects/functions.

Comment: I want to get `naturalHeight` of the image. `$(".crop-image-area .uploaded-image").naturalHeight` worked until today, but now it returns `undefined`. Perhaps, I missed something. Does `naturalHeight` work only on the element object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging two different things:
- the two first ones are jquery objet, which "shows" the objet 'prevObject' when it is logged.
- the last one is an Element object, which log "contains only" the element itself